# Why can I remove Lateinit when a variable is initialized in constructors in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In my mind, I should add `Lateinit` before a variable if I initialize it later.

But I get the following warning for Code A in  Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2, you can see Image A, why ?

*Lateinit is unnecessary: definitely initialized in constructors*

Where can I find the related information in official document?

**Code A**

```
class PreferenceParameterState private constructor(context: Context) {
    lateinit var labelSetKey: String 

    init {
        labelSetKey = context.getString(R.string.preferenceAPIKeySet)
    }
}
```

**Image A**

[image]

**Added Content**

After I remove `Lateinit`, I get the error, you can see Image B.

**Image B**
[image]

Comment: Don't post images of code. Post code as text.

Comment: Your question is literally just the answer. Because it "is initialized in the constructor", that is the definition of not "late". Any initializtion later than the constructor are "late". Directly assigning value inline with the declaration has the same effect of assigning in constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the compiler messages here are a bit confusing. You indeed do not need `lateinit` here, as you initialise `labelSetKey` in an `init` block. `init` blocks are run when initialising an object, so `labelSetKey` will *definitely* be set after you do `PreferenceParameterState(someContext)`.

The purpose of `lateinit` is for when there is some external "thing" that will do the initialisation, that the compiler don't know about, so can't prove that the property will be initialised. From the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables):

> However, it is often the case that doing so is not convenient. For
> example, properties can be initialized through dependency injection,
> or in the setup method of a unit test. In these cases, you cannot
> supply a non-null initializer in the constructor, but you still want
> to avoid null checks when referencing the property inside the body of
> a class.
>
> To handle such cases, you can mark the property with the `lateinit`
> modifier:

So how about the errors that you get when you remove `lateinit`? This is about *when* the `init` block is executed. `init` blocks and property initialisers are run in *textual* order. See the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors):

> The primary constructor cannot contain any code. Initialization code
> can be placed in initializer blocks prefixed with the `init` keyword.
>
> During the initialization of an instance, the initializer blocks are
> executed in the same order as they appear in the class body,
> interleaved with the property initializers:

By putting your `init` block *last*, the `derivedStateOf { ... }` expression is executed first. In that expression, you used `labelSetKey`, which is not initialised at this point!

You might argue that the lambda passed to `derivedStateOf` is not run immediately, and you know that `labelSetKey` will be initialised by the time the lambda runs. The compiler doesn't know that though.

So to fix the error, just move the `init` block up a bit. Put it before all uses of `labelSetKey` and `labelNoSetKey`, but after their declarations.

Comment: Thanks! But I can't place `init{...}` at top of these variables, you can see Image C in my updated content of the question.

Comment: @HelloCW *Please* don't post images of code. Edit your question to post them as text. You should put the `init` block *after* `labelSetKey` and `labelNoSetKey` are *declared*, but before they are *used*. Is that clear?